# JWT signature exception occured after Base64 encoding/decoding Secret and Public keys

Tags: java, jwt, base64, rsa, jjwt

JWT signature exception occured after Base64 encoding/decoding Secret and Public keys.

I generated a key pair like this:

```
KeyPair keyPair = Keys.keyPairFor(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256);
```

Them I incoded keys this way:

```
PrivateKey aPrivate = keyPair.getPrivate();
String encodePrivate = Encoders.BASE64URL.encode(aPrivate.getEncoded());
PublicKey aPublic = keyPair.getPublic();
String encodePublic = Encoders.BASE64URL.encode(aPublic.getEncoded());
System.out.println("encodePrivate: " + encodePrivate);
System.out.println("encodePublic: " + encodePublic);
```

After that I decode keys and try to generate and verify JWTs:

```
SecretKey privateKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(encodePrivate));
SecretKey publicKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(encodePublic));

   String jwtStr = Jwts.builder()
        .setId(id)
        .setIssuedAt(now)
        .setSubject(subject)
        .setIssuer(issuer)
        .claim("dhdfh", "dfhd")
        .claim("cvbcv", "wrwerew")
        .signWith(privateKey)
        .compact();

   Jwts.parserBuilder()
        .setSigningKey(publicKey)
        .build()
        .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
```

And suddenly I get an error
If I use the keys directly like this
`PrivateKey aPrivate = keyPair.getPrivate(); PublicKey aPublic = keyPair.getPublic();` - no error occurs

```
encodePrivate: MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQDTnkqggdMFu5O58pB8U0f8D4pab_7j5T8jNZfEep23DbvoMCjR6X1cFe4qCsvaY4aDF6d6Vn3TVY2INHMuyOTXqe5vhBWiRgaI3TIPkGjgHZ1f6Up_ZPQFJCGTo2b3OiXBq3LTK7PXvMj2EIQPJrHuX099ACDvO-9F8T_nyLA68JLfS-V6OmH-nvaCjqndbVSUxOE69OncpU3kPUpdzPPdi7jhEphTOcKdSE8YvPyAjj8RREgZsWgYn10qql_GEZ8Lh15KuBRwJAJQYeOYU_thC6pObazr7NWbpk1e0_0tDuMrfunbKCca1Wz_xv9M7bn1BD92122wuPkenQg-s0ohAgMBAAECggEAA3vssJ3SkpqXAQ28UT-xxLWgyoJjiO8CThsYx5RZOmVQfa8lTOdyN-zogeqxloPi-A-Qo1P_OFaFQQPUDaYjFmXm1hEvpf9PJju2EkmHYIE8URLvNg-8cMU6hErBbDqZ2olvF4j1qgyipmJ5OiKh9VG-Zkl1QVsUQmuJaNCGDkJWDgCAAnJz-dwjhTV0J_RCeOcDhc5YTik14lVUxFsWm5F0bFbvh_x-ThhgFYwoUZ-ZWIQjPHD2_VraxX76BqOOa1B56p1xeKsz6sEv_jR7G3fSay8mgMxkAakCYoXANedcdtXpBZx8Ad1QBFUOFBGX67hfD_2PydAu5mA9S18_zQKBgQDixlZw1EbzwAVZ-VxURBZ8-Iw0GGYtOYqCJqB771cLuRrCiYfMrUqWE9A3AqtxhasaBYZ5K8m0abET4oZ7QOOajVhBG1N6v1ilQiUsxcYZVqdEhfH_T1olx_wNWT5GqbUb-sUXr4AmtirWypqdGTIixVLUyQkRhtSbJiDLf6bR0wKBgQDu4-tAOiBotp_tW6ZELrZbAxNTfqUDODd-RBYFT-OHL5PXT2PqgpPC0W8JKEerTIXo_hplr-70YOkJYGZwHk84Ptx-cFDjNq86bR10xaFDkLI-omMT4aPQyx67gaNMx07G6AlV9idC-sYi_Db2dUsiJPJ6A8g-aug7MtFA3y_HuwKBgDf0rqGaj4NXrzpbQD_-qPnfLmEwYA3qs9WXiGPsU7Mt0n-MBfkoDU5oxyi7vOf_DpAWKu89McEVjz8T1xEUmtSo6czu3DNegZYNczTP_CiGbDGJR4Qy5VCLPxNgIPC4sVqdDwLgKCPlMT7csTfwXqGbxOuCS32Kom1CBDeSYOxHAoGAXq2qMRxYd-fZXoMyVFeHIm8Hm9HXqH0BUWO-roBJFuz-VRk76leyJEZJEYILVZLQh9UdtSuTMvutoG-6abk5gHs5fEsbY9HqhOd2Ay_IiDSy0CwfxGNrP3chSQNKK0XarO6NtKoISX2GRZtcVTWLf47RIxaYqFRKkhvD30gVcb0CgYB_Bc5sImIZpyVNJ48b9v6u6s0rPQW0q7pI4GstuhVeTlsukf_p76xf6V50F3mbWE7nb-SbVenJxn0naTWPW9oWmBrJX3eYft_HE4OjURQc6aaOuP-1OSPnioVnfYxQ52e5uHa6cTQvaAOcy3vrFjw7VYTp0W95L5ZYTLaa83nxIw

encodePublic: MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA055KoIHTBbuTufKQfFNH_A-KWm_-4-U_IzWXxHqdtw276DAo0el9XBXuKgrL2mOGgxenelZ901WNiDRzLsjk16nub4QVokYGiN0yD5Bo4B2dX-lKf2T0BSQhk6Nm9zolwaty0yuz17zI9hCEDyax7l9PfQAg7zvvRfE_58iwOvCS30vlejph_p72go6p3W1UlMThOvTp3KVN5D1KXczz3Yu44RKYUznCnUhPGLz8gI4_EURIGbFoGJ9dKqpfxhGfC4deSrgUcCQCUGHjmFP7YQuqTm2s6-zVm6ZNXtP9LQ7jK37p2ygnGtVs_8b_TO259QQ_dtdtsLj5Hp0IPrNKIQIDAQAB

JWT!!! eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIxMjM0NTYiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzA1ODIyMjEsInN1YiI6InN1YmplY3RfMiIsImlzcyI6Imlzc3Vlcl8xIiwiZGhkZmgiOiJkZmhkIiwiY3ZiY3YiOiJ3cndlcmV3IiwiZXhwIjoxNjcwNTgyMzIxfQ.V0y0-l7ySBEdmc4X7eRmLlSoxXv5QdpEPedICZOR6zlMRgjFR63mPMn64yqfz8FAvUOaFjyZr-FRgCEFhTk8CA

Exception in thread "main" io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:399)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:529)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:589)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173)
    at Runner.decodeJWT(Runner.java:64)
    at Runner.main(Runner.java:83)
```

I think i'm doing smthng wrong with `publicKey`. I need string representation of keys to keep them in configuration file. Help me to solve this problem please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hopefully the private key is not a productive key

Comment: everything is possible ;)

Comment: What are you doing here? First you create a RS256 keypair. But then what's this `SecretKey privateKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(encodePrivate));` ?  And the token you printed in the last block `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9` shows "alg":"HS512" after decoding. "HS512" is a symmetric algorithm that does not support separate public and private keys. Do you want to use RS256 with public/private keys or HSxxx with a secret?

Comment: @jps I want to use RS256 with public/private keys. `SecretKey privateKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(encodePrivate));` in this row I try to get privateKey from its Base64 string representation (for example from app configuration file), but may be I do it in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake using this:

```
SecretKey privateKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(encodePrivate));
SecretKey publicKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(encodePublic));
```

here is what to use instead:

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPriv = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(prvKeyBytes);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecPubl = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pblcKeyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey prvKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPriv);
    PublicKey pblKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpecPubl);
```